# The boundary of a 3 dimensional manifold is a disjoint union of 2-spheres

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homological-algebra, surfaces

Here is my main goal: I am trying to show that $\partial M$ is a disjoint union of $2$-spheres where $M$ a connected compact 3-dimensional orientable manifold with boundary satisfying $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})=0$.

In the following let it be understood that coefficients are from $\mathbb{Z}$. Also let $i:\partial M\to M$ denote the inclusion.

Here is my progress so far, which to me seems like a promising direction: If the boundary is empty, let's say that the boundary is an empty union of 2-spheres, so assume that $\partial M\neq\varnothing$. Under these assumptions, we know that $\partial M$ is a closed orientable manifold of dimension $3-1=2$ (one dimension lower than $M$). Hence, by the classification of closed orientable surfaces, we know that $\partial M\cong\bigsqcup M_{g_\alpha}$ where $M_{g_\alpha}$ denotes the closed orientable surface of genus $g_\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$. It remains to show that $g_\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha$. My strategy was to show that $$H_1(\partial M)=0\text{ }(*)$$ because I have previously calculated the homology of the surface $M_g$ so by *additivity* of disjoint unions we have $H_1(\partial M)\cong\mathbb{Z}^K$ where $K:=2\sum_\alpha g_\alpha$. The problem have thus far been translated into the problem of showing $\mathbb{Z}^K=0$, from which it follows $g_\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha$. It seems like something which should not be too difficult, yet I have not successfully been able to show it. The strategy that I have tried is to show that $$\mathbb{Z}^K=H_1(\partial M)\stackrel{i_*}{\longrightarrow}H_1( M)=0$$ (which appears in the long exact sequence of the pair $(M,\partial M)$) is injective, which can only be the case if $K=0$.

Consider the following part of the long exact sequence in cohomology of the pair $(M,\partial M)$
$$
H^1(M)\stackrel{i^*}{\longrightarrow}H^1(\partial M)\stackrel{\delta}{\longrightarrow}H^2(M,\partial M)
$$
where $H^2(M,\partial M)\cong H_1(M)=0$ as a consequense of Lefschetz duality, so $i^*$ is in fact surjective. Here is a specific question of (homological) algebraic nature, which is something I do not have a strong background in

> Since the first homology groups of both $M$ and $\partial M$ are free, can we from the naturality of the universal coefficient theorem deduce that $i_*$ is injective because the vanishing of the Ext-term yields a natural isomorphism of the cohomology group and its dual?

I hope the question makes sense. I would also love to know if that approach is completely hopeless or not, and in case it is, I would appreciate it if someone could tell if there is a better way to go.

Comment: This is informally known as "half lives, half dies," $2 rank(H_1(M))= rank(H_1(\partial M))$, see Lemma 3.5 in Hatcher's notes on 3-dimensional topology, [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/3M/3Mfds.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continue from the long exact sequence of cohomology,
$$\ldots\to H^1(M)\overset{i^*}{\to} H^1(\partial M)\to 0$$
By UCT, we also have
$$H^1(M;\Bbb Z)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_1(M;\Bbb Z),\Bbb Z)\oplus \operatorname{Ext}(H_0(M;\Bbb Z);\Bbb Z)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(M;\Bbb Z);\Bbb Z)\cong 0$$
The second isomorphism is due to the fact that $H_0$ is free, and the third isomorphism is because $H_1(M)$ vanishes (assumption). So, the exact sequence above is actually
$$0\overset{i^*}{\to}H^1(\partial M)\to0$$
which implies that $H^1(\partial M)\cong 0$. Apply UCT again, $\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(\partial M;\Bbb Z),\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z^{b_1}\cong 0$, where $b_1$ is the betti number in dimension $1$, and it is immediate that $b_1=0$, which should proves your claim. (I'm not sure why you're thinking about showing the injectivity of $i_*$.)

Comment: This is much simpler, thank you. Don’t know why it did not cross my mind to think of that. Say I had successfully showed that $i_*$ is injective, that would imply the Betti number is zero right? Moreover, is there not a dual relation like “surjective in cohomology” iff “injevtive in homology” - I know it holds for “isomorphism”

Comment: Your "if and only if" is not tru because of the following case. It is not true in general that "Injectivity on homology implies surjectivity on cohomology". Consider the homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z^2, 1\mapsto (2,0)$. Then, consider the dual $\phi^*:\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb Z^2,\Bbb Z)\to\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z),\psi\mapsto \phi\circ\psi$, note that $\eta:x\mapsto 3x$ is not in the image, since if it were then $\psi\circ\phi:x\mapsto(2x,0)\mapsto 2xa$ (always even) as $\psi\in\operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb Z^2,\Bbb Z)$ is determined by the image of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. @Ellefee

Comment: @Ellefee For your first doubt: If you can show that $i_*$ is injective, then it also works, but I'm afraid that it will take longer to actually write down a rigorous proof.

Comment: For that "iff" statement to be true, I think there should be more restrictions, but adding to many assumptions is not going to help us in more general questions, since those (co)homology groups are not very "friendly". By the way, there is a typo in the third line of my first comment. That should be $\psi\mapsto \psi\circ\phi$..